# Unresolved compilation, “XX” cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am trying to find a mode of an array of `ints` in Java.

I am getting the exception:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: maxValue cannot be resolved to a variable at tez3.main(tez3.java:34)" error.

My code is below. What is the problem?

Update: Solved, i am adding the code below. Thanks to Elliott Frisch

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tez3
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
{
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:\\tny\\Deneme1.txt"));
int [] numberList = new int [10];
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
int result = 0;
while(s.hasNextInt()){
    numberList[i++] = s.nextInt();
}
for (i=0; i<numberList.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(+(i+1) +".Value: " +numberList[i]);
}
for (i=0; i<numberList.length;i++)
{
    count++;
}

for (i=0; i<numberList.length;i++)
{
        result += numberList[i];
}

System.out.println("Average of the Values is: " +result/count);
System.out.println("Mode of the Values is: " +mode(numberList));   
}

public static int mode(int numberList[])
{
int maxValue=0, maxCount=0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; ++i) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < numberList.length; ++j) {
        if (numberList[j] == numberList[i]) ++count;
    }
    if (count > maxCount) {
        maxCount = count;
        maxValue = numberList[i];
    }
}

return maxValue;
}

}
```

Comment: You're not calling `mode()`.

Comment: Did you mistake `maxValue` for `maxCount`?

Comment: `maxValue` is defined in the `mode()` method, not `main()`. You can't use local variables of other methods like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `maxValue` is only visible in the `mode` function, which you aren't calling. Change

```
System.out.println("Average of the Values is: " +maxValue);
```

to

```
System.out.println("Average of the Values is: " +mode(numberList));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but when i do that, i get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The local variable maxCount may not have been initialized
 The local variable maxValue may not have been initialized

error. what can i do for that ?

Comment: Great. Now fix `mode`. Where you have `int maxValue, maxCount;` - what values should those have? They're not set.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you so much for your attention, i fixed it.