# Linked list cannot be resolved

Tags: java

So first of all I am new to this side, so please don't be to hard if I make some formal mistakes.

So I am trying to learn a bit about linked lists in Java. I created now a linked list in the main method, which is called "liste" and a method called "addToList", which should add a string to my list.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedLists{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> liste = new LinkedList<String>(); 
        addToList("Mario");
    }

    public static void addToList(String pElement) {
        liste.add(pElement);
    }

}
```

When I add an element in the main method and print it out, it works fine, but when I do it this way I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    liste cannot be resolved

        at LinkedLists.addToList(LinkedLists.java:11)
        at LinkedLists.main(LinkedLists.java:7)
```

Comment: The scope of `liste` is limited to the `main()` method. Therefore you cannot access it in `addToList()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolved compilation, “XX” cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123902/unresolved-compilation-xx-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the visibility of the `liste` variable.

When you define the variable inside a method it is visible only inside the method.

For a variable to be visible across the class it has to be defined as an attribute.

**EDIT I**

> But could you please explain what you did excactly? I don't understand
>   why there are two lists

Why the problems related to static methods and calls when calling methods or attributes directly from `main()`?

As the declaration indicates `public` **static** `void main(String args[])` is a `static` method (which by the way is the starting point of execution for the java program).

Static methods and attributes are common to all instances of a class, and exist even is there is no instantiated object of that class.

Non static attributes and methods are local to each instantiated object (attributes for different objects can take different values), hence they depend on an object to have been instantiated.

When a static method like `main()` runs, there is no guarantee that the non static attributes will exist, and even if they existed in one or more objects, there would be no way to target a specific instance, therefore you can't call non static methods or use non static attributes in a static method.

But the program starts with a static method: `main()`. So what you do is inside main() you create the instances you need to run the program, and call the necessary non static methods and attributes on these created objects. You can see `main()` as the place where objects can do their stuff.

In the example, the class LinkedList**s** holds both, the main method to start the execution, and the methods and attributes to implement the logic of the LinkedList**s** objects (this becomes clearer when this class is used from a different class that holds the `main()` method).

So in the static method `main()`, we create an instance of the LinkedList**s** class, on which we can call the non static methods.
When an object is instantiated (with `new LinkedLists()`) this new object has its own copy of a `liste` attribute, which can be operated on by calling non static methods on this ojbect.

In this case we are working with just one LindedList**s** object, but, potentially we could have more than one instance of the class, each one with its own backing `liste` attribute, and operate on one or other according to our needs.

```
public class LinkedLists{
    private LinkedList<String> liste = new LinkedList<String>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedLists linkedListsInstance= new LinkedLists();
        linkedListsInstance.addToList("Mario");
        linkedListsInstance.printList();

    }

    public void addToList(String pElement) {
        liste.add(pElement);
    }

    public void printList(){
        System.out.println(liste);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well when i try to do this one it gives me the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field liste"

Comment: Right, it should be called on an instance of LinkedLists, let me make ammendments, you don't want to use a static variable for this...

Comment: It works a bit better, but now I got this problem: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field liste
 at LinkedLists.main(LinkedLists.java:8)"

Comment: remove the static word from public static void addToList(String pElement) {. Static attributes and methods, have a specific usage, it is not a good idea to start learning oop with that.

Comment: I did but still the same error. The compiler says that the problem is in line 8 thats where it create the new list

Comment: It should work now, I also added a second method to print the contents of the list, to show the concept. Sorry for the last examples, the names of classes got me dizzy.

Comment: Oh nice one that worked, thans :) But could you please explain what you did excactly? I don't understand why there are two lists

Comment: I changed the name of the instance and provided some background to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable `liste` in the function `addToList`. But the variable is defined in the `main` function and not available in `addToList`.

Lets walk through the error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

So compilation did not work because

> liste cannot be resolved

The symbol `liste` is not know to the compiler. It could not resolve its meaning.

> at LinkedLists.addToList(LinkedLists.java:11)

The top most entry shows you where the compiler encountered this problem. In this case it is the `addToList` function in file `LinkedLIsts.java` on line 11.

If you want to share `liste` with `addToList` you can either pass it as a parameter:

```
public class LinkedLists{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> liste = new LinkedList<String>(); 
        addToList(liste, "Mario");
    }

    public static void addToList(LinkedList<String> liste. String pElement) {
        liste.add(pElement);
    }
}
```

or you move it out of `main` into the scope of `LinkedLists`:

```
public class LinkedLists{

    static LinkedList<String> liste = new LinkedList<String>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addToList("Mario");
    }

    public static void addToList(String pElement) {
        liste.add(pElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay and how can I make it available?